# Evosuite as Intellij plugin

Tags: plugins, failed-installation, evosuite

I have been trying to upload Evosuite as Intellij plugin from disk but it's failing to load plugin descriptor from the zip file available in the github repository. Would you be able to help me with it?

Tried to install evosuite as a plugin  in intellij but have been facing issues with that.